# Flutter: How to avoid change orientation?

Tags: orientation, flutter

I have a final user design with landscape orientation.  User doesn't want/need portrait and it is needed to avoid automatic orientation change on iOS/Android. How can I achieve that?

Comment: please find this updated answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50884081/348589

Answer (score 18):

[`SystemChrome`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemChrome-class.html) is what you want

You can do something like in main.dart (don't forget import 'package:flutter/services.dart')

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
]);
```

Unfortunately, when I do this in my application, the orientation will *always* be `landscapeRight`.

To lock the orientation for iOS you need to change the settings for the XCode project (use command 'open ios/Runner.xcworkspace' in terminal to open it)

Comment: Any import needed? Inside main()? or class MyApp?  Please be a little more specific. Red underlined over SystemChrome (Undefined name) and DeviceOrientation too. Thanks.

Comment: Any import needed? YES! import 'package:flutter/services.dart'.   Inside main()? YES.  or class MyApp? MAYBE YES!. Thanks.

Comment: @abnerh69 - To lock the orientation for iOS you need to change the settings for the XCode project (use command 'open ios/Runner.xcworkspace' in terminal to open it)

Comment: Did somebody know, why upside down doesn't work? DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp does not working.

Comment: Is there any way to lock the orientation of a specific screen of an app, rather than for all screens of the app?

Answer (score 15):

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft])
    .then((_) {
      runApp(new MyApp());
    });
}
```

`SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations` returns a Future. Wait until that’s done and then we can start our app.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line of code in your main.dart file
`SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);`