# Flutter: how to prevent device orientation changes and force portrait?

Tags: flutter, dart, orientation, portrait

I would like to prevent my application from changing its orientation and force the layout to stick to "portrait".

In the main.dart, I put:

```
void main(){
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown
  ]);
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

but when I use the Android Simulator rotate buttons, the layout "follows" the new device orientation...

How could I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you imported `'package:flutter/services.dart'`, then maybe it's a bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13238

Comment: Not sure why this happens to you. I tried running your code on an emulator and also my own device and it works fine.

Comment: `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations` returns asynchronously, so seems like `runApp` should be enclosed in a `then`.

Comment: @Ken is correct. Make `main()` async and put `await` in front of `SystemChrome...`

Answer (score 425):

Import `package:flutter/services.dart`, then

Put the `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations` inside the `Widget build()` method.

Example:

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      ]);
      return new MaterialApp(...);
    }
  }
```

**Update**

This solution mightn't work for some IOS devices as mentioned in the updated flutter documentation on Oct 2019.

They Advise to fixed the orientation by setting UISupportedInterfaceOrientations in Info.plist like this

```
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

For more information https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27235#issuecomment-508995063

Comment: If you put SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations in main you will get the error: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.   Inserting the code in build works because bindings have been initialized at this point.

Comment: Reminder that for iOS info.plist, you have to set it for iPad as well under <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>

Comment: I hid the Android task bar with `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
        overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);` and adding this makes it appear again for a moment and then it goes away when I tap something to navigate.  Is this by design?  I have the above snippet nested in void initState() for whichever page I want to hide Android task bar and your snippet in build of my top level screen that main runs.

Answer (score 167):

@boeledi, If you want to “lock” the device orientation and not allow it to change as the user rotates their phone, this was easily set as below,

```dart
// This did not work as required
void main() {   
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

> You have to wait until **`setPreferredOrientations`** is done and then
> start the app

```dart
// This will always work for lock screen Orientation.
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Comment: It sometimes throws an error while compiling, you should use native solutions. 
Adding 'android:screenOrientation="portrait"' to MainActivity on AndroidManifest as Abeer Iqbal's suggests worked for me on Android.

Answer (score 132):

#### iOS:

Calling `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations()` doesn't work for me, and I had to change the `Device Orientation` in the [Xcode project](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2244/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009012-CH1-STATUS_BAR) as following:

[image]

#### Android:

Set the [`screenOrientation`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#screen) attribute to `portrait` for the main activity in the file `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` as following:

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem, did you run it on an iPad? I only tested on an iPad and this seems to be an issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27235

Comment: android: This attribute was added in API level 24.

Comment: I use `screenOrientation` since API level 8 for Android. @BloodLoss , I think you read it on the docs, but about `resizeableActivity` attribute. Check the link again. ^^

Comment: This worked perfectly on Flutter 2.5 except the Android status bar I was hiding has returned.

Comment: @Boy you should change this configuration on info.plist  for ipad <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
 <array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
 </array>

Answer (score 70):

Open android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and add the following line in the MainActivity:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

If you have this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

You should end up with something like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

This works for Android. On iOS, you will have to change this from the Xcode page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hswoe.png (as Hejazi said)

Comment: thanks ,REMEMBER the order of "portrait" after the configChanges "orientation" does matter.

Comment: cleanest way so far

Answer (score 60):

Put the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` else you will get an error while building.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

    void main() async => {
          WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
          await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
              [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp],
          ); // To turn off landscape mode
          runApp(MainApp());
        };
```

Answer (score 28):

The 'setPreferredOrientations' method returns a Future object. 
Per documentation a Future represents some value that will be available somewhere in future. That's why you shall wait until it's available and then move on with the application. Hence, there shall be used 'then' method, which, per definition, "registers callbacks to be called when the Future completes". Hence, you shall use this code:

```
  void main() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]).then((_) {
      runApp(new App());
    });
   }
```

Also, the following file must be imported:

'package:flutter/services.dart'

Comment: I can confirm this works. But use whenComplete() instead of then(), when the function got no param.

Answer (score 19):

First of all import this in **main.dart** file

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Then **don't copy paste** rather see(remember) and write below code in **main.dart** file

To force in **portrait** mode:

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
      .then((_) => runApp(MyApp()),
  );
}
```

To force in **landscape** mode:

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight])
      .then((_) => runApp(MyApp()),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding people not to copy-paste blindly

Comment: I see why you asked NOT to copy paste ... the ending } is missing... I copy pasted... :)

Answer (score 13):

**Flutter orientation lock: portrait only**

In Flutter we have SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientation() ([see documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setPreferredOrientations.html)) to define preferred orientation. Exactly this method you can find in all those articles about setup orientation in Flutter. Let’s see how we can use it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  // We need to call it manually,
  // because we going to call setPreferredOrientations()
  // before the runApp() call
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
  // Than we setup preferred orientations,
  // and only after it finished we run our app
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((value) => runApp(MyApp()));
}
```

**iOS**

Open project in Xcode `(ios/Runner.xcworkspace)`, choose `Runner` in the project navigator, select Target `Runner` and on Tab `General` in section D`eployment Info` we can setup Device Orientation:

[image]

Also, we can do it manually without opening Xcode at all — just edit `ios/Runner/Info.plist`. Open it as a text file, find key `UISupportedInterfaceOrientation` and leave only desired values:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

**Android**

To define orientation for `Android` we need to edit `ApplicationManifest`. Open `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and add an attribute screenOrientation for a `main` activity:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.orientation_lock_example">
    <application ...>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            ...
            />
            ... 
        </activity>
        ... 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And that’s all. [Here](https://github.com/greymag/flutter_orientation_lock_example) is the repository with an example app:

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 9):

Import `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

Then you include the line of code below in your `main.dart` file, and in your main method like so:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);

runApp(myApp());
```

Answer (score 9):

For people, that they are reading this question now.
The easiest way that I found and it worked on both android & ios devices.

```
 void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ],
  ).then((val) {
    runApp(YourAppName());
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add the following line of code in the main.dart file.

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
]);
```

and remember to import services.dart file. An example is given below!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      ]);

      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(child: Text("A Flutter Example!")),
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> **You have two options for for android**

***1. Write for on main***

```
    main() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
          .then((_) {
        runApp(
          child: MyApp(),
        );
      });
}
```

***2. Set from natively on `AndroidManifest.xml` file***
[image]

> **You have also two option for iOS**

***1. from `info.plist`***

add this line to your `info.plist` file

```
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

***2. from Runner***
open your `Runner.xcworkspace` from iOS folder on your Xcode. Click on Runner not Pods. You can find this option on General>Deployment Info. just check what you want
[image]

Answer (score 5):

`setPreferredOrientation` returns a `Future<void>`, so it is asynchronous. The most readable approach is to define `main` as asynchronous:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  return runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I strongly disagree. `await` is a ubiquitous programming pattern that is present in multiple languages, and it's very clear what expressive. `then` creates levels of nesting. If you have three or four continuations, `then` starts to become very difficult to read indeed.

Comment: `.then` can be chained instead of nesting, as it expects a `FutureOr`. This allows me to use a more functional approach, which is more readable and elegant. For example, I can use expression body instead of bracketed body by chaining the "thens".

Comment: It sometimes throws an error while compiling, you should use native solutions. Adding 'android:screenOrientation="portrait"' to MainActivity on AndroidManifest as Abeer Iqbal's suggests worked for me on Android.

Comment: If you are facing an error: "Unhandled Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized." try using this fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689492/flutter-unhandled-exception-servicesbinding-defaultbinarymessenger-was-accesse

Answer (score 4):

Below is the official example of the flutter team.
https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/veggieseasons/lib/main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show DeviceOrientation, SystemChrome;

void main() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    runApp(HomeScreen());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To force portrait in iPad, you also have to modify key `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` in `ios/Runner/Info.plist`:

```
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
```

This can also be done through XCode.

Above will work locally. In order to upload to the App Store through XCode, you also have the add the following to `Info.plist`. This can also be done by checking "Requires full screen" under Target->General->Deployment Info.

```
   <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
   <true/>
```

Otherwise you'll get an error while uploading.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
          [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]); 
    
      runApp(MyApp());
 }
```

You can also change the screen orientation settings in the android manifest and ios info.plist file.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to enable the `requires fullscreen` option in iOS case.

```
void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      ]).then((_) {
        runApp(MediaQuery(
            data: MediaQueryData(),
            child:
                MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: LoginPage())));
      });
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of new flutter versions along with setting the `preferred Orientation` we need to add one extra line i.e

```
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

So working code for this is -

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    void main() {
          WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
          SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
            DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
            DeviceOrientation.portraitDown
          ]);
          runApp(MyApp());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution has worked for me on two different projects for Android. Can't guarantee it will work for iOS too. I've read all the previous answers and I think the best and simplest solution is to do it like this:

### Android:

This way you avoid all the "await"s, "async"s and "then"s that might mess around with your code

```dart
/// this is in main.dart

main(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/root',
      routes: {
        '/root': (context) => MyApp(),
      },
      title: "Your App Title",
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// ENFORCE DEVICE ORIENTATION PORTRAIT ONLY
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown
    ]);

    /// RUN THE APP
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

### iOS:

I think [this answer's update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50884081/9185411) is your best bet for iOS.

!! DISCLAIMER !!
I did a little bit of research and apparently, the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setPreferredOrientations.html) specifically says:

```
setPreferredOrientations method Limitations:

"This setting will only be respected on iPad if multitasking is disabled."
```

[Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27235#issuecomment-507984206) is how you can disable multitasking (AKA turn on "Requires Full Screen" option) from XCode

### Another possible fix for iOS

You might also try [this one](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27235#issuecomment-508995063) out. I haven't tried it personally, since I don't have an iPad or XCode on my PC, but it's worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing this from the xcode interface, it will not be changed for ipad. For the ipad section, you must edit the info.plist file from the android studio. You can see in the array list like that "~ ipad". There are two sections available in info.plist, you have to manually edit it for both iphone and ipad.

Answer (score 0):

To make `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations` to work on iPad, enable "Requires full screen" in Xcode project editor or simply add the following lines in /ios/Runner/Info.plist in your project folder.

```
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
<true/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple way ->

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your camera screen is still rotate in some case (iPhone 14 Plus, my case), after setting

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]); in
```

App Startup dart file then add below code where you initiate camera controller.

```
await cameraController.lockCaptureOrientation(DeviceOrientation.portraitUp);
```

Answer (score 0):

One scenario where `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations()` won't work (even on iPhone) is where - for whatever reason - you have put your `FlutterViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`.

In this case, as is expected iOS behaviour, it is the `UINavigationController` which is responsible for handling orientation changes, not the `FlutterViewController` (which is why `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations()` won't work).

To force a given orientation in this case, you should therefore subclass the `UINavigationController` and specify the orientations you wish to support:

```swift
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { .portrait }
}
```