# How to force the application to Portrait mode in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
void main(){
  ///
  /// Force the layout to Portrait mode
  /// 
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown
  ]);

  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Please find this updated answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50884081/348589

Answer (score 12):

Put this code in the MyApp() and don't forget to import the services package:

```
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
```

Like below:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      ]);
      return new MaterialApp();
    }
  }
```

**Update**

There is a bug which prevents this code working on ipads github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27235 as per comment by @F-1.

Below comment may help you out.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27235#issuecomment-508995063

Comment: I just edited this but it doesn't seem to work anyway...at least not in iOS.

Comment: @Hasen I have added the code which is working perfectly.

Comment: There is a bug which prevents this code working on ipads https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27235

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code working for both `Android` and `iOS`

```
Future main() async {
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Comment: At time of writing this won't work on iPads https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27235

Answer (score -2):

Following code worked for me.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/splashScreen.dart';

    void main() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      ]);

  runApp(MaterialApp(home: splashScreen(),));
}
```