# Flutter how to disable landscape orientation?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to disable the landscape mode. I tried to allow only portrait mode using following code. But it is not working with my physical device. How to solve this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to paste the code in `Widget build()`. Consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418332/flutter-how-to-prevent-device-orientation-changes-and-force-portrait) for more details

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      ]);
      return new MaterialApp(...);
    }
  }
```