# Flutter Table for multiple column display

Tags: flutter, datatable

Have been trying to display data on a table, I used Datatable but my only 4 columns show, and the rest hidden. And most of the titles of columns show the error "Right overflowed by 12 pixels" but when I turn my device landscape it shows others and some still hidden. Below is my code:

```
                 body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Rejected',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),

                    Material(
                    elevation: 3.0,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    color: colorBlue,
    child: MaterialButton(
    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
    onPressed: () async {

    },child: Text(
      "ADD NEW",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
    )
                    ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),

                  DataTable(
                    columns: [
                      DataColumn(label: Text('No')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('PO Ref')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Req Ref')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Requester')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Supplier')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Created')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('By')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Delivery')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Status')),

                    ],
                    rows: [
                      DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(Text('1')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),

                      ]),
                      DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(Text('2')),
                        DataCell(Text('John')),
                        DataCell(Text('9')),
                        DataCell(Text('John')),
                        DataCell(Text('9')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),


                      ]),
                      DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(Text('3')),
                        DataCell(Text('Tony')),
                        DataCell(Text('8')),
                        DataCell(Text('Tony')),
                        DataCell(Text('8')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),


                      ]),
                    ],
                  ),
                ]))
```

Is there a way I can make just this page landscape to see all my data without hiding and removing the overflowed error?

Comment: If you're using Row then try to wrap the widget. And please share the complete code

Comment: I just updated my full code. Am using SingleScrollView() to wrap it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve this by simple adding `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,` inside my `SingleChildScrollView` below is now my updated code:

```
                     body: SingleChildScrollView(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,//this is the line of code added
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Rejected',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),

                    Material(
                    elevation: 3.0,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    color: colorBlue,
    child: MaterialButton(
    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
    onPressed: () async {

    },child: Text(
      "ADD NEW",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
    )
                    ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),

                  DataTable(
                    columns: [
                      DataColumn(label: Text('No')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('PO Ref')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Req Ref')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Requester')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Supplier')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Created')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('By')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Delivery')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Status')),

                    ],
                    rows: [
                      DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(Text('1')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),

                      ]),
                      DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(Text('2')),
                        DataCell(Text('John')),
                        DataCell(Text('9')),
                        DataCell(Text('John')),
                        DataCell(Text('9')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),


                      ]),
                      DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(Text('3')),
                        DataCell(Text('Tony')),
                        DataCell(Text('8')),
                        DataCell(Text('Tony')),
                        DataCell(Text('8')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),


                      ]),
                    ],
                  ),
                ]))
```

Answer (score 1):

your table widget add in **SingleChildScrollView()** and add **scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,**

```
body: Container(
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Rejected',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  )),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),

              Material(
                  elevation: 3.0,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                    onPressed: () async {

                    },child: Text(
                    "ADD NEW",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  )
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              //add this scrollview & ScrollDirection
              SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Container(
                  child: DataTable(
                    columns: [
                      DataColumn(label: Text('No')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('PO Ref')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Req Ref')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Requester')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Supplier')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Created')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('By')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Delivery')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Status')),

                    ],
                    rows: [
                      DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(Text('1')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),

                      ]),
                      DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(Text('2')),
                        DataCell(Text('John')),
                        DataCell(Text('9')),
                        DataCell(Text('John')),
                        DataCell(Text('9')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),


                      ]),
                      DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(Text('3')),
                        DataCell(Text('Tony')),
                        DataCell(Text('8')),
                        DataCell(Text('Tony')),
                        DataCell(Text('8')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),
                        DataCell(Text('Arya')),
                        DataCell(Text('6')),


                      ]),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the `SingleChildScrollView()` widget to make the page scrollable and display the contents of the table , not sure about how to make the device landscape though. You can look at this thread and see if it answers your landscape problem : [Flutter: how to prevent device orientation changes and force portrait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418332/flutter-how-to-prevent-device-orientation-changes-and-force-portrait)

Comment: I just updated my code, I used SingleChildScrollView(), and still the same error. Also, I followed the link you gave and this is to make the whole application portrait but I want only this page to be landscape and others portrait.