# Lock screen orientation of flutter web application in mobile device

Tags: flutter

I'm developing responsive flutter web application. I want my application to be suggested only in portrait orientation, since I did not consider the landscape mode for the application. Is there any way to lock screen orientation for the flutter web application?

Comment: Check the following thread, it discusses your exact wish. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418332/flutter-how-to-prevent-device-orientation-changes-and-force-portrait

Comment: I already tried that but didn't work for me. It keeps changing its orientation when I click rotate button.

Comment: is it web application? That can be opened only from browser?

Comment: It is web application. I build it by `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).orientation` with `RotatedBox` to artificially lock it.
By that I mean to use orientation switch in build method and conditionally rotate content to always have correct aspect ratio. You use `RotatedBox` on highest level to rotate the whole thing

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RotatedBox(...)
}
```

Comment: In your index.xml file, change

window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";

to

window.flutterWebRenderer = "canvaskit";