# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Tags: flutter, dart

Suddenly this error appears in the debug console. I do not know what I did wrong.

[image: Error image]

Comment: are you using agora???

Comment: No I'm not using agora

Comment: This helped me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70467105/15823478

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You've upgraded Flutter but not the packages. In the terminal enter

`flutter pub outdated`

Then upgrade the outdated packages one by one like this:

`flutter pub upgrade outdated_package`

After you're finished:

`flutter clean`

and

`flutter pub get`

Your problem should now be solved.

Comment: flutter upgrade, flutter clean, flutter pub get will also do the job

Comment: Not worked. Flutter version: 3.0.5 Dart: 2.17.6

Comment: You can just upgrade the firebase_core package to the latest. That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: The upgrade command is wrong. The correct command is: flutter pub upgrade outdated_package or more specifically: flutter pub upgrade firebase_core. Can you fix this? I'm willing to bet it's causing folks some lost time.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore (if it once did)

Comment: Upgrading to the latest version doesn't seem to fix this issue

Comment: I am having a problem when installing shared_preferences, and I followed these instructions, but it doesn't work now.

Comment: Oh I use Android Studio and I tried restarting Android Studio and it worked, so the above instructions still work

Answer (score 10):

I spent a long time looking into this and eventually traced it to the plugin registrar being `nil` when setting up the plugin.

This was caused by setting my iOS app root view controller to anything other than `FlutterViewController` (i.e. in my case, I had a  `UINavigationController` as the root). **This will result in a failure to register all your plugins.**

The app delegate assumes that the root view controller is a `FlutterViewController`, so if it isn't then you will need to re-direct all plugin-related function calls to your `FlutterViewController` from your app delegate by overriding these functions as follows:

```swift
    override func registrar(forPlugin pluginKey: String) -> FlutterPluginRegistrar? {
        flutterViewController.registrar(forPlugin: pluginKey)
    }

    override func hasPlugin(_ pluginKey: String) -> Bool {
        flutterViewController.hasPlugin(pluginKey)
    }

    override func valuePublished(byPlugin pluginKey: String) -> NSObject? {
        flutterViewController.valuePublished(byPlugin: pluginKey)
    }
```

Comment: This answer really needs more upvotes. The error happens exactly because of this. Sometimes the plugin registrar files are just out of date (or missing) and the commands in other answers fix them, but in some cases you might setup `FlutterViewController` wrong - especially in case of not having FlutterAppDelegate. So this answer gives you the correct direction. Helped me out a lot @jonathan, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for looking into the root cause. I then solve the problem by adding `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: ...` as the documentation said. (I was using the codes in *Create a FlutterViewController with an implicit FlutterEngine* section of the document so I somehow missed that PluginRegistrant thing.)

Comment: Oh and by the way, if your `FlutterViewController` is inside a `UINavigationController`, you'll also find that `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations()` won't work either. I've just posted a workaround to that problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76191411/555485) (posting here as I reckon people will be looking at this answer who are likely to run into this issue!)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and stumped on this post.

In my case I was able to detect which plugin was in fact giving the error and it turned out to be `firebase_core`. So, I decided to upgrade the package to the latest version which happened to be `1.21.1` in my case.

So, to solve the issue I will suggest you try changing the version of the `firebase_core` package you're using to the latest in the **pubspec.yaml** file of your project like so:

```
firebase_core: ^1.21.1 (replace with latest verison)
```

Or you can just run:

```
flutter pub upgrade firebase_core
```

This will upgrade `firebase_core` to the latest version.

Or you can as well put any as the version code in the **pubspec.yaml** file of your project like so:

```
firebase_core: any (upgrades firebase_core to the latest verison)
```

Comment: It's not firebase_core, it's path_provider for the root reason caused this issue.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest version doesn't seem to fix this issue

Answer (score 3):

Running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Please also check the `compileSdkVersion` in `android/app/build.gradle` and update it to 33

Answer (score 2):

If you are using these dependecies then replace it with a latest version:

- firebase_messaging
- firebase_core
- flutter_local_notifications

Then in `android/app/build.gradle` update `compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion` to 33

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, After 1 day of trying, I realized that the variable I was passing to createUserWithEmailAndPassword() had no value.
This function was working totally fine when I was passing hardcoded value i.e. email & password

Answer (score 1):

I also effected from that issue for few hours, finally I found issue that was I ran my emulator as windows (:, yeah please run with Android emulator you selected vm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was trying to use "google_mobile_ads" and "admob_flutter" at the same time. You must choose one only.

Answer (score 1):

Try out different devices like Chrome or Android if you run into this error.
Note that firebase does **not** run on all platforms flutter runs on.

In my case I was developing on Linux and got that PlatformException because I was launching the app as a  Linux program - which is not supported by Firebase and thus raises the error even though everything is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was have this problem.
after downgrade awesome_notifications package to 0.6.21, resolved this.

Answer (score -2):

This error also occurs when using a package which does not support the current development platform such as a package does not support flutter windows development or IOS and when you try to use it on an unsupported platform then it will throw this error.

for example using flutter_toast on windows (So far flutter_toast does'nt support windows).
first cross check whether the added package support the current development platform or not.
I hope this will help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).