# Getting PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null) for my Flutter Project

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have tried the solution provided at: [Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72880037/unhandled-exception-platformexceptionchannel-error-unable-to-establish-connec)

However, all dependencies in my project are up to date.

I have specified minSdkVersion 21 and multiDexEnabled true in my android/app/build.gradle file as well.

Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It turns out that the application name was not matching between the firebase_options.dart and android/app/build.gradle. I updated the code to make them match and it worked.

Comment: What application name? There's no application name in firebase_options.dart. I created my project using `flutter create mytrial`, my firebase project is called `flutter-auth`. When you say, "my application name was not matching" between those two files, care to explain *exactly* what you mean? I'm facing a similar issue, and although you marked yourself an answer, your answer more vague than the original error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check the firebase_auth dependency version in your app, in my case, when the firebase_auth version is ^4.4.2, then the intl package version should be 0.17.0.

```
  intl: ^0.17.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.4.2
```