# Getting this error while connection with firebase using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSxZg.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72880037/17180860

Answer (score 0):

try this :

Run in the terminal,

```
flutter pub outdated
```

Next, update the packages which are outdated

```
flutter pub upgrade outdated_package
```

Then, run `flutter clean` next `flutter pub get`

Comment: Hey! I've done running these commands

Comment: What happens when running?

Comment: It show this error 

Exception has occurred. PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null))

Comment: Do you use firebase_core package?

Comment: Yes added it in the dependency

Comment: ok, replace firebase_core: ^2.4.1 in dependency. run flutter pub upgrade firebase_core

Comment: is it not ok, try --> change android/app/build.gradle update compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion to 33

Comment: First suggestion, Same issue
Second, how to update?

Comment: Go to android in your app and next app next open build.gradle in Android studio. There is compileSdkVersion. update it  flutter.compileSdkVersion to 33

Comment: Thanks for you precious time but issue is still there as I didnt get how to update compileSdkVersion

Comment: Do I need to update api level to 33 in android studio

Comment: Did you find the android folder of your project?

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1:

> In `pubspec.yaml` have you added `firebase_core`?

- Step 2:

> If no then please goto `pub.dev` and find the latest version    of it
> and add to `pubspec.yaml`

- Step 4: into main.dart add this

  ```
  Future<void> main() async {
         WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
         await Firebase.initializeApp();
  ```

  }
- Step 3:

> If yes, then run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`

Comment: I've done all these things
Please help unable to solve the issue from 2 days

Comment: Which flutter SDK are you using?

Comment: How to know about version?

Comment: Please run into terminal flutter doctor -v

Comment: Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1105], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.5)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

Comment: my solution should be work as per your flutter version

Comment: I've updated flutter to latest

Comment: Thats fine ....

Comment: Your issue was resolve?@Unknown_Coder