# Flutter: M1 Macbook Pro Image_Picker Error

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage, apple-m1, flutter-image-picker

I'm new to Flutter and would love some help with an error.

While using the image_picker package, I noticed that I'm getting a value of null returned when I try to select an image from ios photo gallery.
(Specifically, [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.)

I read the package documentation where it says this is a known issue and to try it on a real device. I tried it on my real device an only got the desired result once. Can someone please shed some light on this? Below, I have provided the necessary code and a look and my flutter doctor. Thanks in advance!

P.S. To be clear, I am trying to test this on my physical ios device(iPhone 14 Pro Max), as I am aware of the issue with the ios Simulator and the image_picker package.

Please let me know if I need to provide more information to resolve this issue!

```
 String? photoUrl = " ";
File? image;

 Future pickImage() async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker()
          .pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, requestFullMetadata: false);
      if (image == null) return;

      Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("profilepic.jpg");
      await ref.putFile(File(image.path));
      await ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {print(value); setState(() {
        photoUrl = value;
      });});
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Failed to pick image: $e');
    }
  }

  profilePic() {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SizedBox(
      height: size.height * 0.185,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(children: [
        const Spacer(),
        photoUrl != null
            ?
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  pickImage();
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 120,
                  width: 160,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(20),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    size: 50,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ):Image.network(photoUrl!),
      ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on macOS 12.6.1 21G217 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
> • Flutter version 3.7.0 on channel stable at /Users/myronsp/Developer/flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision b06b8b2710 (9 days ago), 2023-01-23 16:55:55 -0800
> • Engine revision b24591ed32
> • Dart version 2.19.0
> • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/myronsp/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
• ANDROID_HOME = /Users/myronsp/Library/Android/sdk
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14C18
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] Connected device (5 available)
• sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
• Myron’s iPhone (mobile)     • 00008120-00016D500A80C01E            • ios            • iOS 16.0.2 20A380
• iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile)  • B8ACBFEA-35E5-4D2C-810C-46100D17EE63 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2 (simulator)
• macOS (desktop)             • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.6.1 21G217 darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)                • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 109.0.5414.119

Answer (score 0):

hope you are included all the required steps for accessing gallery in android and iOS  [as mentioned here](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker).

other chances are out dated packages in the flutter project.

please check the following link to rectify that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72889709/7159206)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did in fact already have the required permissions in my info.plist. I updated my packages as you suggested, unfortunately I am still experiencing the same error. I did also specifically upgrade firebase_core as it was suggested in the link you provided. Again, thanks for your answer, back to the drawing board I go for this one.

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding correctly, below your spacer widget in your column children the condition should be `photoUrl == null` instead of `photoUrl != null`.

It would be good if you can share some findings.

Comment: Thanks so much for your insight on this. I changed my code to photoUrl == null; however, now I am getting a new error that says 

The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///%20

Is there more information I can share to better explain my issue?