# After Flutter Update: Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Tags: flutter, dart

> [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
> #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:210:7)
>
> #1      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:29:44)
>
> #2      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73:7)
>
> #3      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
>
> #4      main (package:actify_app/main.dart:49:3)
>
> Syncing files to device iPhone 14 Plus...                          385ms

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.0, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-x64, locale en-DE)
• Flutter version 3.10.0 on channel stable at /Users/tristanwieser/Developer/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 84a1e904f4 (8 days ago), 2023-05-09 07:41:44 -0700
• Engine revision d44b5a94c9
• Dart version 3.0.0
• DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
• Android SDK at /Users/tristanwieser/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14E222b
• CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• iPhone 14 Plus (mobile) • 1E7952C8-0AC1-48E2-A90D-C76C1606EEE7 • ios            •
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
• macOS (desktop)         • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a
darwin-x64
• Chrome (web)            • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 113.0.5672.126

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

name: actify_app
description: A new Flutter application.

my pubspec.yaml:

```
> The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
> pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
> publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
> 
> The following defines the version and build number for your application.
> A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
> followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
> Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
> build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
> In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
> Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
> In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
> Read more about iOS versioning at
> https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
> version: 1.0.0+1
> 
> environment:
> sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"
> 
> 
> dependencies:
> geocoding: ^2.0.0
> geolocator: ^9.0.2
> flutter_typeahead: ^4.3.8
> google_sign_in:
> flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.9
> flutter:
> sdk: flutter
> flutter_localizations:
> sdk: flutter
> adobe_xd: ^2.0.1
> google_fonts: ^4.0.3
> firebase_core: ^2.13.0
> firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.8.0
> firebase_analytics: ^10.1.0
> firebase_auth: ^4.6.1
> firebase_storage: ^11.0.10
> firebase_messaging: ^14.6.1
> cloud_firestore: ^4.7.1
> google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
> smooth_star_rating_null_safety: ^1.0.4+2
> image_picker: ^0.8.3+2
> dropdown_search: ^5.0.5
> filter_list: ^1.0.2
> camera:
> path_provider: ^2.0.15
> path: ^1.8.2
> table_calendar: ^3.0.0
> url_launcher: ^6.0.20
> 
> dependency_overrides:
> firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.8.0
> 
> 
> The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
> Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
> cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
> mailto: ^2.0.0
> flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
> font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0
> google_places_flutter: ^2.0.5
> 
> dev_dependencies:
> flutter_test:
> sdk: flutter
> test:
> 
> 
> For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
> following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
> 
> The following section is specific to Flutter.
> flutter:
> 
> The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
> included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
> the material Icons class.
> uses-material-design: true
> 
> To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
> assets:
> assets/images/
> assets/logos/
> 
> An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
> https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
> 
> For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
> https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
> 
> To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
> in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
>   # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
> list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
> example:
> fonts:
> family: Schyler
> fonts:
> asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
> asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
> style: italic
> family: Trajan Pro
> fonts:
> asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
> asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
> weight: 700
>   #
> For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
> see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

my podfile:

```
> Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
>  platform :ios, '13.0'
> 
> CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
> ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
> 
> project 'Runner', {
>   'Debug' => :debug,
>   'Profile' => :release,
>   'Release' => :release,
> }
> 
> def flutter_root
> generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
> unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
> raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
> end
> 
> File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
> matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
> return matches[1].strip if matches
> end
> raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
> end
> 
> require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)
> 
> flutter_ios_podfile_setup
> 
> target 'Runner' do
> use_frameworks!
> 
> flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
> end
> 
> 
> pod 'GooglePlaces'
> 
> post_install do |installer|
> installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
> flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
> target.build_configurations.each do |config|
> config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
> 
> end
> end
> end
>
```

Hi there,

basically the error occurred after updated to the newest flutter version 3.10.0.

I've tried a lot of stuff and as well as multiple options provided in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72880037/unhandled-exception-platformexceptionchannel-error-unable-to-establish-connec).

The app is running on android emulator but not on Ios emulator.
I am clueless what to do, so if you have any ideas, please feel free to comment below.