# PlatformException on Firebase.InitializeApp

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I'm having problem starting Firebase after migrating to SDK 33 and Gradle 8.
Error:

> PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to
> establish connection on channel., null, null))

Part of the code:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
module:
  androidX: true

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4 #1.1.1
  http: ^0.13.3
  flutter_math_fork: ^0.7.1
  intl_utils: ^2.2.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1 #^2.3.1
  provider: ^6.0.5 #4.3.2+3
  textstyle_extensions: ^2.0.0-nullsafety
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0-alpha.1
  # login added function
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.11 #4.0.1 #3.5.7 #3.3.3+1 #2.0.0 ^4.4.0+1
  image_picker: ^1.0.4 #0.6.7+21
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.0 # 2.1.3
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0-nullsafety.0
  image: ^4.1.3
  flutter_html: 3.0.0-beta.2
  html_unescape: ^2.0.0
  pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0
  clipboard: ^0.1.3
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
  page_transition: ^2.0.2
  badges: ^3.1.2
  overlay_support: ^2.1.0
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
  photo_view: ^0.14.0 #0.11.1
  image_cropper: ^4.0.1
  vibration: ^1.7.4-nullsafety.0
  vibration_web: ^1.6.5-nullsafety.0
  youtube_plyr_iframe: ^2.0.4
  permission_handler: ^11.0.1
  what3words: ^3.1.0-nullsafety.3
  geolocator: ^10.1.0  
  video_player_web: ^2.1.2
  wakelock_web: ^0.4.0
  flutter_rounded_date_picker: ^3.0.4
  share_plus: ^7.2.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.2
  local_auth: ^2.1.7
  url_launcher: ^6.2.1
  firebase_core: ^2.24.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.6
  firebase_auth: ^4.15.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/img/
    - assets/icon/
    - assets/payment/
    - lib/lang/en.json
    - lib/lang/mn.json
  fonts:
    - family: Mogul
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/mogul.ttf  


flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
```

Project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace 'com.my.package'
    compileSdk 33
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/kotlin', 'build/generated/source/buildConfig/release', 'build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug']
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId 'com.my.package'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true

            ndk {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
            }

        }

    }
    lint {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.3.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Flutter Doctor -v:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2715], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.16.1 on channel stable at C:\Development\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7f20e5d18c (3 days ago), 2023-11-27 09:47:30 -0800
    • Engine revision 22b600f240
    • Dart version 3.2.1
    • DevTools version 2.28.3

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\MSM\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.11.27)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise
    • Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 version 16.11.33801.447
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)

[√] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\MSM\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.76.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)       • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2715]
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 119.0.6045.124
    • Edge (web)              • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 119.0.2151.93

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

I already tried:

- flutter clean, flutter pub upgrade, flutter pub outdated
- adding firebasebom to gradle and removing it
- already installed Flutterfire CLI and flutterfire configure
- Debugging on android device, same results

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72889709/21590733

Comment: I already tried and all firebase packages are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have updated Flutter but forgot to synchronize the packages.
run this in your terminal:

`flutter pub outdated`

and then

`flutter pub upgrade outdated_package`

Then clean and build once more.

Comment: I get following output but flutter pub upgrade seems not affect those dependencies.

`Package Name           Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest

direct dependencies:
flutter_facebook_auth  *5.0.11  *5.0.11     *5.0.11     6.0.3
google_fonts           *4.0.4   *4.0.4      *4.0.4      6.1.0
http                   *0.13.6  *0.13.6     *0.13.6     1.1.2
image_cropper          *4.0.1   *4.0.1      *4.0.1      5.0.1
You are already using the newest resolvable versions listed in the 'Resolvable' column.
Newer versions, listed in 'Latest', may not be mutually compatible.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your app in release mode it can help to find the root cause of crashing

Running commands:
App by default runs on debug mode, it is a bit janky but needed to provide features like hot reload and hot restart. However, if you want to run the app in other modes, try these commands:

```
Release mode:

flutter run --release
Profile mode:

flutter run --profile
```

[image]