# I get this error and my app crash in the simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

I have already updated all the : firebase_core , Firebase_messaging , flutter but still have the error

I get this error only with IOS but not with android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72889709/21590733

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72880037/unhandled-exception-platformexceptionchannel-error-unable-to-establish-connec)

Answer (score 0):

You've upgraded Flutter but not the packages. In the terminal enter

```
flutter pub outdated
```

Then upgrade the outdated packages one by one like this:

```
flutter pub upgrade outdated_package
```

After you're finished:

```
flutter clean
```

and

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to mentioned your channel_id and channel_name if you want to push notification service.

Changes in AndroidManiFest.xml

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <!-- added for firebase push notification configuration  -->
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="high_importance_channel" />
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Just run this command flutter pub outdated
And then upgrade outdate package by running this command flutter pub upgrade outdated_package
Then flutter clean and flutter pub get
Don't forget to install pod i think this will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).