# Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/channel-error] Unable to establish connection on channel

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to integrate OTP based verification in my flutter app with firebase. The steps that I have done till now are:

1. Pubspec.yaml consist of these packages
   a. firebase_auth: ^4.16.0
   b. firebase_core: ^2.24.2
2. Configured firebase and connected it with the flutter app, generated the firebase_options.dart file.

This is how my code looks in main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

This is how my login page looks

```
import 'package:faekbank/screens/testScreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl_phone_field/intl_phone_field.dart';

class PhoneNumberRegistration extends StatefulWidget {
  const PhoneNumberRegistration({super.key});

  @override
  State<PhoneNumberRegistration> createState() =>
      _PhoneNumberRegistrationState();
}

class _PhoneNumberRegistrationState extends State<PhoneNumberRegistration> {
  String curPh = '';
  bool codeSent = false;
  String otp = '';
  String verifyId = '';
  bool deliberateLoader = true;
  bool codeSendRequested = false;
  TextEditingController phoneNumber = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController otpController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double curHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double curWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double htpx = curHeight * 1 / 800;
    double wtpx = curWidth * 1 / 360;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: wtpx * 21),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 43 * htpx,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Image.asset('assets/images/faekbank_logo.png'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 34 * htpx,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Tell us about yourself",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 34 * htpx,
                  ),
                  // ChextWidgets.chextField(
                  //     context: context,
                  //     hintText: "Enter Phone Number",
                  //     enabled: !codeSent,
                  //     countryCode: true,
                  //     initialCountryCode: 'IN',
                  //     onChanged: (changedText) {
                  //       setState(() {
                  //         if (changedText != null) {
                  //           curPh = changedText;
                  //         }
                  //       });
                  //     },
                  //     isPhoneNumber: true),
                  IntlPhoneField(
                    controller: phoneNumber,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Phone Number',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                            width: 2),
                      ),
                    ),
                    initialCountryCode: 'IN',
                    onChanged: (phone) {
                      print(phone.completeNumber);
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 13 * htpx,
                  ),
                  codeSent
                      ? TextField(
                          controller: otpController,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              hintText: 'Enter OTP'),
                        )
                      : SizedBox(
                          height: 48 * htpx,
                        ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 45 * htpx,
                  ),
                  Image.asset('assets/images/onboarding_phone_number_deal.png'),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 60 * htpx,
                  ),

                  codeSent
                      ? ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
                                verificationCompleted:
                                    (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
                                verificationFailed:
                                    (FirebaseAuthException ex) {},
                                codeSent:
                                    (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    codeSent = true;
                                    verifyId = verificationId;
                                  });
                                },
                                codeAutoRetrievalTimeout:
                                    (String verificationId) {},
                                phoneNumber: phoneNumber.text.toString());
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
                            backgroundColor:
                                Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            "Confirm",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
                          ),
                        )

                      // This button will be visible once the otp has been sent.
                      : ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            try {
                              PhoneAuthCredential credential =
                                  await PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                                      verificationId: verifyId,
                                      smsCode: otpController.text.toString());

                              FirebaseAuth.instance
                                  .signInWithCredential(credential)
                                  .then((value) {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            const TestScreen()));
                              });
                            } catch (e) {
                              print("This is your error: $e");
                            }
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
                            backgroundColor:
                                Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            "Confirm",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
                          ),
                        ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    "Your data from this app is end to end encrypted",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 82, 81, 81),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea, how to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72889709/21590733

Comment: I have seen this @VivekChib. It didn't help. And also updating all the packages together is not a very good move, as it raises many compatibility constraints.

Comment: try flutter clean and pub get, then rebuild your project.