# Flutter_vlc_player: Unable to establish connection on channel when init controller

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, libvlc

```
I/flutter ( 5004): PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
I/flutter ( 5004): #0      VlcPlayerApi.create (package:flutter_vlc_player_platform_interface/src/messages/messages.dart:658:7)
I/flutter ( 5004): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 5004): #1      VlcPlayerController.initialize (package:flutter_vlc_player/src/vlc_player_controller.dart:191:5)
I/flutter ( 5004): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 5004): #2      VlcPlayerController.onPlatformViewCreated (package:flutter_vlc_player/src/vlc_player_controller.dart:984:7)
I/flutter ( 5004): <asynchronous suspension>
```

It works on other examples but shows me this issue on my project

Comment: Does this answer your question? Possibly helpful or related otherwise (e.g. update Flutter packages) ...[Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72880037/unhandled-exception-platformexceptionchannel-error-unable-to-establish-connec)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No, I tried the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72880037/unhandled-exception-platformexceptionchannel-error-unable-to-establish-connec and no way. After a long debug, i found the probléme with flutter flutter_background_service and i didn't get the reason