# How to block rotation on Flet python (Flutter)

Tags: python, flet

I have a problem that when I turn the device over, the contents get mixed up, are there any ways to prevent the phone screen from turning over?

```py
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Routes Example"

    troute = ft.TemplateRoute(page.route)

    if troute.match("/books/:id"):
        print("Book view ID:", troute.id)
    elif troute.match("/account/:account_id/orders/:order_id"):
        print("Account:", troute.account_id, "Order:", troute.order_id)
    else:
        print("Unknown route")
        
    def route_change(route):
        page.views.clear()
        page.views.append(
            ft.View(
                "/",
                [
                    ft.AppBar(title=ft.Text("Flet app"), bgcolor=ft.colors.SURFACE_VARIANT),
                    ft.ElevatedButton("Visit Store", on_click=lambda _: page.go("/store")),
                ],
            )
        )
        if page.route == "/store":
            page.views.append(
                ft.View(
                    "/store",
                    [
                        ft.AppBar(title=ft.Text("Store"), bgcolor=ft.colors.SURFACE_VARIANT),
                        ft.ElevatedButton("Go Home", on_click=lambda _: page.go("/")),
                    ],
                )
            )
        page.update()

    def view_pop(view):
        page.views.pop()
        top_view = page.views[-1]
        page.go(top_view.route)

    page.on_route_change = route_change
    page.on_view_pop = view_pop
    page.go(page.route)


ft.app(target=main)
```

I tried to cheat, check if the screen width exceeds the norm, but the whole screen shows a message that it should be flipped for more convenient use

Comment: Not sure about Flet, but in Flutter it's relatively easy using flutter/services: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418332/flutter-how-to-prevent-device-orientation-changes-and-force-portrait